# Why is this a non exhaustive search pattern?

Tags: haskell, recursion

Why is this non-exhaustive, doesn't dropping an element mean this should eventually stop?

```
do_something :: [(String, String, Int)] -> String
do_something [(a, b, c)] = func(a, b, c) ++ do_something( drop 1 [(a, b, c)])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to specify every case for a list of `(String, String, Int)` in your declaration of `do_something`.  You have to give the definition for when the argument passed to `do_something` is empty or contains more than 1 element.  The compiler doesn't know what to do automatically when you haven't specified these cases.

Another way to look at it is that pattern matching in a function declaration is the same as using a case statement:

```
do_something :: [(String, String, Int)] -> String
do_something xs = case xs where
    [(a, b, c)] -> func (a, b, c) ++ do_something (drop 1 [(a, b, c)])
    -- What about the other cases?
    -- otherwise -> ???
```

Also, in this case it'd be much better to specify your function as

```
do_something (x:xs) = func x ++ do_something xs
do_something [] = ???
```

Since this actually defines the function recursively.  The expression `drop 1 [(a, b, c)]` is the same as just writing `[]`, so your current definition is equivalent to

```
do_something [(a, b, c)] = func (a, b, c) ++ do_something []
```

Comment: He actually only gave the case for when there's exactly one element -- the exact opposite of what you say here.

Comment: @DanielWagner Whoops, in my head it was "You have to give the definition ..."

Comment: Then `do_something` starts to look like `concatMap func`.

Comment: @raymonad It does look like that's the case, but it could also be that OP wants some other behavior on `do_something []`.  Since it's not specified I left it open-ended.